# Yii2: 'Save Draft' button

Tags: validation, post, yii2

I'd like to have a form with the three buttons:

1. OK button: It runs validation and post data on success.
2. Cancel button: Skip validation and posting and redirect to the other view.
3. Save Draft button: Post data without validation.

I know how to implement OK and Cancel buttons, but how to prevent the validation on 'Save Draft' button click?

Comment: you should use `$model->save(false)` to avoid the `validation` and keep a column as a flag like `is_draft` and keep it `1` in case of saving as draft so you can identify complete and incomplete `data` .

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, thanks for answer! I understand how to operate on the server side. But how to suppress the client validation? Tried to return true from onAfterValidate function withot the success. Server action is not executed.

Comment: Hmm that might be tricky to bypass the client-end validation just for the draft button, what i would suggest is **not to use the submit button for the Draft** , use normal button and save the draft using ajax call , this would trigger the validation if you are typing into the field or blur out but not if you hit the draft button. use `$.serialize()` to get the form inputs and send call to save as draft.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam, thanks a lot! It works.

Comment: you are welcome buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope it will help for someone.
Here is the solution:

Add 'Draft Button' as a normal button in your view:

```
<?= Html::button('Save Draft', ['class' => 'btn btn-default btn-block', 'id' => 'save-draft-btn']) ?>
```

Add JS file to your view and specify onClick event for the button:

```
$('#save-draft-btn').on('click', function (e) {
    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: draftUrl,
       data: $('#report-index').serialize()
    });      
});
```

Add the action to your controller:

```
public function actionSaveDraft($idSupply)
{
    //load models like this
    $report = \app\models\Reports::findOne($idSupply);

    //fill with the POST data
    $report->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    //save without validation
    $report->save(false); 

    //inform the user on success saving
    Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Draft Saved');

    //redirect to the editing page
    return $this->redirect(['index', 'idSupply' => $report->id_supply]);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

To bypass the client-end validation just for the draft button, what i would suggest is **not to use the submit button for the Draft** , use normal button and save the draft using ajax call , this would trigger the validation if you are typing into the field or blur out but not if you hit the draft button. use `$.serialize()` to get the form inputs and send call to save as draft.